# Cloning only used part of Ext4 partition

Tags: hard-drive, backup, ssd

I have a 320GB HDD. 100GB holds `/`, out of which only 30GB is used, and rest holds `/mnt`. I am planning to buy a 64GB SSD. And I can only use one HDD at a time. How can I create an image of that 30GB used space only, in an external drive and restore it by plugging in the SSD?

Clonezilla seems to backup the whole disc, not just the partition. Same with `dd` it seems.

Answer (score 0):

[FSArchiver](http://fsarchiver.org/) is able to restore to a smaller partition.  It works at the file level, and the data format is more resilient to corruption than Partimage's or Clonezilla's.  It's available in GParted-Live and Clonezilla-Live, among others.